# List intersection for multiple matching instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set-intersection

I have an algorithm whose functionality is dependent upon the number of matching instances (even repeated) between two lists. For example:

```
a = ["test", "win", "win", "bike", "bike", "bike", "gem", "nine"]
b = ["test", "win", "let", "bike", "four"]

d = set(a).intersection(b)
```

Would give me:

```
{"test", "win", "bike"}
```

The output I would like, would be:

```
{"test", "win", "win", "bike", "bike", "bike"}
```

I figure I could just utilize the output list and do a count for how many times each intersected word exists in `list a` etc... But this is quite a few extra steps, and I am hoping there is a simpler way to achieve this output.

My question is, based on the provided example lists, how can I achieve the desired second output  of:

```
{"test", "win", "win", "bike", "bike", "bike"}
```

Comment: you should use a list. The main purpose of using a set is to keep a unique record of each element.

Comment: what if you had 2 bike in list b?? how would the resultlook like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` to obtain the counts of each distinct item, and use the `Counter.elements` method to produce the desired list with items repeated according to counts after filtering them by membership in `b` (convert `b` to a set for efficient membership lookups):

```
from collections import Counter
set_b = set(b)
print(list(Counter({k: c for k, c in Counter(a).items() if k in set_b}).elements()))
```

This outputs:

```
['test', 'win', 'win', 'bike', 'bike', 'bike']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a list instead of a set, and you can take advantage of the code you have already defined, so:

```
a = ["test", "win", "win", "bike", "bike", "bike", "gem", "nine"]
b = ["test", "win", "let", "bike", "four"]

s = set(a).intersection(b)

output = []

for e in s:
    n = max(a.count(e), b.count(e))
    output.extend([e] * n)

>>> output
['win', 'win', 'bike', 'bike', 'bike', 'test']
```

Basically, what you are doing is to repeat the common elements considering in which list it is repeated the most.

Comment: This is fine for small lists like the one above, but would get pretty slow when the input size increases.